# Adding a circle boundary in a TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

I *almost* figured out how to draw what I want by piecing together two answers here (@Ignasi for [TiKZ matrix of objects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226613/tikz-matrix-of-objects) and @alexraasch for [L shaped boxes in tikz matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324176/l-shaped-boxes-in-tikz-matrix/324186#324186)).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mycell/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm},
    dot1/.style={mycell,
        append after command={\pgfextra \fill (\tikzlastnode) 
        circle[radius=10pt]; \endpgfextra}},
    dot2/.style={mycell,
        append after command={\pgfextra \fill[white] (\tikzlastnode)  
        circle[radius=10pt]; \endpgfextra}},
    dot3/.style={mycell,
        append after command={\pgfextra \draw[thick] (\tikzlastnode) 
        circle[radius=10pt]; \endpgfextra}},  ]

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={mycell}, nodes in empty cells]
{
|[dot2]|&&&|[dot1]|&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&|[dot1]|&\\
|[dot1]|&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&|[dot3]|&&&&\\
};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path [fill=black!10]
      (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.south west)
   -- (m-2-2.south east) -- (m-3-2.south east)
   -- (m-3-5.south east) -- (m-2-5.north east)
   -- (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-1-3.north east)
   -- cycle;

\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.south west)
   -- (m-2-2.south east) -- (m-3-2.south east)
   -- (m-3-5.south east) -- (m-2-5.north east)
   -- (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-1-3.north east)
   -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

creates

[image]

I want the white disc in the m-1-1 position (a dot2) to have a black boundary as in m-6-2 (a dot3). My naive efforts of combining `\draw` and `\fill` didn't work.  I'm open to entirely different solutions if what I want is tricky with the code I spliced together.

Comment: Just as a comment, you could also use unicode characters U+25CB and U+25CF.

Comment: Today's [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1988/) is very appropriate to my approach to TikZ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>To the upvoters: please don't upvote this very trivial answer!</sup>

Use `\draw[fill=white, thick]` instead of the simple `\fill[white]`.

Moreover, you don't need to write the path of your gray area twice, one to fill and one to draw, you can do it with a unique command (I added `very thick` only to highlight it).

As percusse pointed out in his comment, you can use perpendicular paths (`|-`) to shorten your code, and, as you realized by yourself, `dot3` is useless since you can use `dot2` for both cases of white dots.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        mycell/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm},
        dot1/.style={mycell,
            append after command={\pgfextra \fill (\tikzlastnode) 
                circle[radius=10pt]; \endpgfextra}},
        dot2/.style={mycell,
            append after command={\pgfextra \draw[fill=white, thick] (\tikzlastnode)  
                circle[radius=10pt]; \endpgfextra}}, 
        ]

    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={mycell}, nodes in empty cells]
    {
        |[dot2]|&&&|[dot1]|&&\\
        &&&&&\\
        &&&&|[dot1]|&\\
        |[dot1]|&&&&&\\
        &&&&&\\
        &|[dot2]|&&&&\\
    };

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[fill=black!10, very thick] (m-1-1.north west) |- (m-2-2.south east) |- (m-3-5.south east) |- (m-2-3.north east) |-cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With perpendicular paths you can save some typping: `\draw[fill=black!10, very thick] (m-1-1.north west) |- (m-2-2.south east) |- (m-3-5.south east) |- (m-2-3.north east) |-cycle;`

Comment: @CarLaTeX (and @Ignasi) Thanks so much.  With the improved dot2 I don't think dot3 is necessary.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Yes, it is not necessary :)